# Swift: "NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134092" when executing CNSaveRequest of Contact Store

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift-package-manager

I'm writing a command line program with Swift Package Manager that uses Contacts API to automatically add phonetic names for the contacts. However, I found I was unable to do so for contacts that has notes. First, when I was trying to enumerate the contacts, there is a strange error output:

```
2023-01-22 18:58:36.085525+0800 PhoneticNames[18591:98356] [core] Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
    "com.apple.account.CardDAV",
    "com.apple.account.Exchange",
    "com.apple.account.LDAP"
)}
2023-01-22 18:58:36.085580+0800 PhoneticNames[18591:98356] [accounts] CNAccountCollectionUpdateWatcher 0x6000003ccc40: Store registration failed: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"
2023-01-22 18:58:36.085606+0800 PhoneticNames[18591:98356] [accounts] CNAccountCollectionUpdateWatcher 0x6000003ccc40: Update event received, but store registration failed. This event will be handled, but the behavior is undefined.
2023-01-22 18:58:36.136236+0800 PhoneticNames[18591:98344] [api] Attempt to read notes by an unentitled app
```

According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_contacts_notes), I need to add the notes entitlement only if I was requesting the note field with CNContactNoteKey. However, I was not requesting it and I still get that "Attempt to read notes by an unentitled app" error.

Here is my code for enumerating the contacts:

```swift
let keys: [CNKeyDescriptor] = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
                               CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .phoneticFullName)]
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
fetchRequest.mutableObjects = true
do {
    try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { (contact, stop) in
        contacts.append(contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact)
    }
} catch {
    print("unable to list contacts. \(error)")
}
```

And this is how I update the contacts later:

```swift
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
contact.phoneticFamilyName = phoneticFamilyName
contact.phoneticMiddleName = phoneticMiddleName
contact.phoneticGivenName = phoneticGivenName
saveRequest.update(contact)
do {
    try store.execute(saveRequest)
} catch {
    print("Fail to execute store request: \(error)")
}
```

This code works as expected for contacts without the note field. But for contact with a non-empty note field, the saveRequest fails and outputs the following error:

```
2023-01-22 18:58:36.197026+0800 PhoneticNames[18591:98344] [error] error: Unhandled error occurred during faulting: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134092 "(null)" ({
})
CoreData: error: Unhandled error occurred during faulting: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134092 "(null)" ({
})
```

I am using Swift 5.7, Xcode 14.2, macOS 13.1. I looked for all the documents but couldn't find anything about NSCocoaErrorDomain Code 134092.

I shouldn't receive the error "Attempt to read notes by an unentitled app" when I am not requesting notes. And I should be able to successfully execute the `saveRequest` that doesn't modify the note field. Does anyone knows how these error comes?